# Validating Data in form before adding data to backbone collection

Tags: validation, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Hi i am a newbie to backbone.
I am trying to follow http://listen-dom-events-backbone.herokuapp.com/.
I edited the html so as to input three attributes : Name age and occupation

```
<form id="addPerson" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the person" id="name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Age" id="age">          
        <input type="text" placeholder="Occupation" id="occ">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Person">
</form>
    <script id="personTemplate" type="text/template">
<span><strong><%= name %></strong> (<%= age %>) - <%= occupation %></span> 
<button class="edit">Edit</button>
<button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </script>
```

And the Validation of my backbone is something like this.

```
App.Views.AddPerson = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#addPerson',

events: {
    'submit': 'submit'
},

submit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newPersonName = $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();
    var newage = $(e.currentTarget).find(age).val();
    var newocc = $(e.currentTarget).find(occ).val();
    var person = new App.Models.Person({name: newPersonName, age: newage, occupation: newocc});

            // Only when the data exists it has to be added to the collection
            // This is what i tried

           // Method 1: 
    var attributes = person.attributes();
    validate: function(){
        if(attributes.newage ==null){alert("Please Enter Age")}
    if(attributes.newocc ==null){alert("Please enter occupation")}      
    }

            //Method 2
            var attributes = person.attributes();
    validate: function(attributes){
        if(attributes.newage !=null){person.set({age: newage});}
        if(attributes.newocc !=null){person.set({occupation: newocc});
            }

            // Only if everything above is correct this value should be returned
    this.collection.add(person);

}
```

});

Am i doing this right or there is something wrong ?

Comment: I solved it this way:
var newPersonName = $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();
  var newage = $(e.currentTarget).find(age).val();
  var newocc = $(e.currentTarget).find(occ).val();
  if (newPersonName != ''){
  if (newage != ''){
  if (newocc !=''){
   var person = new App.Models.Person({ name: newPersonName , age: newage, occupation: newocc});
   this.collection.add(person);
  }
  }
  }
is this the right way or is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation should be done in the model, this is how backbone is desgined. If you look at the documentation, you will see that there is a `validate` method, a `isValid` method as well as a `validationError` property in the model, which start making sense when you override the `validate` method.
So your `validate` method in the `Person` model could for example be defined like this.

```
App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // some other methods
  validate: function(attributes, options) {
    var errors = [];
    if(_.isEmpty(attributes.age)) {
      errors.push("age missing");
    }
    if(_.isEmpty(attributes.occupation)) {
      errors.push("occupation missing");
    }
    if(!_.isEmpty(errors)) {
      return errors;
    }
  }
});
```

you will then be able to call `isValid` on your model, and in case it is not, the validation errors returned by your `validate` method will be avaiblable through the `validationError` attribute. You could then change your submit method to something like this:

```
 submit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.model.isValid()) {
      // do what you want with your model
    } else {
      alert(this.model.validationError.join('\n'));
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is correct. Additionally, to help with synching the form with the model, get the modelbinder plugin. It will automatically trigger validation failures on blur without needing to first submit the form. https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder

Comment: Just one small doubt.
when calling the validate function with isValid(), can we just call isValid() or should it be like this isValid(this.model.attributes) ???
and in validate:function(attributes, options), what is the options for ?
coz without attributes or options also validate is working for me ?
@ChrisCamaratta

Comment: Yes, you can just call `isValid()` with no parameters.

Comment: `isValid` is not documented properly, but you can pass an option hash which will be passed to `validate`. 
The `attribute` parameter is not relevant when you are using `isValid`. `isValid` will pass all your model attributes to the `validate` method so you do not need to care about it. `attributes` parameter in `validate` is relevant when you are using `save` or `set` on the model, in which case only the needed attributes can be validated. For more information look at the documentation and/or the source code of Backbone.